# C# Setting value on enum member variable of a singleton, lags the Unity editor

Tags: c#, enums, singleton, unity-game-engine

I have a singleton implemented with static instance variable approach.
When I set one of it's member variable of `enum` type, the editor lags and I have to force quit it everytime that happens.

```
public class SharedData {

    private static SharedData m_onlyInstance = null;


    public int a,b,c;
    public ESampleType eType = ESampletype.Default;


    public static SharedData Instance {
        get {
            if (m_onlyInstance == null) {
                m_onlyInstance = new SharedData();
            }
            return m_onlyInstance;
        }
    }
    //other codes...
}

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Slider m_sliderTest;

    public void onStartBtn(){

        Debug.Log("---START---");

        SharedData data = SharedData.Instance;

        ESampleType eType = (ESampleType)(int)m_sliderTest.value;

        data.a = 1;
        data.eType = eType;  //***when I commented this line, the lag disappear.
        data.b = 2;
        data.c = 3;

        Debug.Log("---END---");

    }
    //other codes...
}
```

Also, the log `"---START---"` and `"---END---"` won't show up when the problematic line is there. It seems doesn't compile well. It's very weird!

Is this a limitation on C#? Please help me what's happening here. I need to fix this problem.

My Unity editor version is `5.4.1.40776`.

Comment: You need to include a private constructor in your singleton class.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I have it in my original code. I just didn't include it in my dummy code here.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem inherent to the code. Maybe taking this issue to the Unity forums or QA site will turn up more meaningful answers.

Comment: no monobehaviours?

Comment: @Bijan the TestClass is monobehaviour. I'll edit it.

Comment: onStartBtn is called via button event?

Comment: @Bijan yes. that's the structure of my original code. I just made it simple here and remove some sensitive details.

Comment: But the point of my problem is there's a weird bug happening on editor when an enum member variable of a singleton is assigned a value.

Comment: @Abion47 Alright! Thanks for the advice! =)

Comment: if the dummy code also has the issue, it must be unity bug.

Comment: Do you think there's a probability for multiple button events trying to access your singleton instance at the same time? Like if you are firing a lot of events at the same time, that _might_ cause a problem

Comment: I've used a very similar pattern in Unity and it works fine - I would imagine your issue is that some infinitely looping code gets triggered whenever your `eType` is not `ESampleType.Default`. `Debug.Log` entries don't show up in the editor if it crashes (the Unity main thread also updates the console; if you lock up the main thread, it never redraws the console).

Comment: As a side note, if the above is true, you'll see both `START` and `END` in the editor log file immediately after it crashes. To get the file location, click the small menu icon in the top right corner of the console window, then click "Open Editor Log".